# SoapClient and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, soap-client

I'm trying to send request using SoapClient to WSDL file but am receiving this error

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\SoapClient' not found

I tried to add `\SoapClient->callSoap()` or `use SoapClient;` am still getting error and my soap extension is enabled.

Here is my code in controller:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://adm.com/api/service.php?wsdl');

$headerbody = array('OrgId'=>'4AWisEr','OrgKey'=>'ikaroXajiD');
$header = new SoapHeader('https://adm.com/api/service.php?wsdl','credentials',$headerbody);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$result = $client->emailExists($email);

return $result;
```

Answer (score 3):

Just tried this and I did not get a namespace error:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use SoapClient;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $client = new SoapClient('https://adm.com/api/service.php?wsdl');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you restart PHP after installing? What version of PHP are you using? If you run `php -i` from the command line, do you see the extension?